# Location of genes encoding ribosomal proteins

Tags: cell-biology

I have cited two sources below: the first, a textbook, says ribosomal proteins are imported into the nucleolus (from the cytoplasm) where initial ribosome assembly occurs.
The second is a journal which asserts, in the first paragraph, that ribosomal **protein** **mRNA** is processed in the nucleoplasm, distinct from the nucleolus.

I am therefore very curious about the location of ribosomal **protein** **genes** whose transcript is the mRNA; specifically whether these are located in the nucleolar region or not.

Sources:

1. "Histology a text and an atlas" by Michael H. Ross and Wojciech Paulina. 6th Edition; pg. 79.
2. "Nuclear and Nucleolar Targeting of Human Ribosomal Protein S6" (Carola Schmidt, Edgar Lipsius, and Joachim Kruppa) ; Vol. 6,1875-1885, December 1995.

Comment: This is a [previous answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45864/are-ribosomes-assembled-in-rough-er-and-golgi-body-or-in-the-nucleolus/45865#45865) to a question on this topic. It references a review of the topic with a poster that summarizes the situation. Of course all proteins in eukaryotes are translated in the cytoplasm, so any proteins that are required in the nucleus have to be reimported.

Comment: @David, I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. I am interested in knowing whether the genes that encode the mRNA which then gets translated into ribosomal proteins are part of the nucleolar region or not.

Comment: Ok. Look at the distribution of ribosomal protein genes across different chromosomes. Massively diverse. Why would you expect the genes in the nucleolus if the mRNA has to go to the cytoplasm? It’s the rRNA transcripts that need to be in the nucleolus and the ribosomal proteins etc. to move there from the cytoplasm after synthesis.

Comment: Ok. This helps.